# Symfony 3: Overriding Default UserBundle Templates

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twig, fosuserbundle, symfony

i want to override the Friendsofsymfony Userbundle Templates. I found already the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

But i guess its not working in symfony3. The structur of the bundle is diffrent.
I think in the original its bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Ressources/views.
By me its vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views.

I already try to copy this structur to the app folder. But it still not working.

thx for reading and maybe helping

Comment: F*** ... forgotten to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) about overriding bundle templates:

> When the `AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig` is rendered, Symfony actually looks in two different locations for the template:
>
> 1. `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/index.html.twig`
> 2. `src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Blog/index.html.twig`
>
> To override the bundle template, just copy the `index.html.twig` template from the bundle to `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/index.html.twig` (the `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle` directory won't exist, so you'll need to create it). You're now free to customize the template.